# How unique is the US system of publicly registering with a political party?

Tags: voter-registration

### Short version

Does any country apart from the USA have a voter registry that includes an option to register with a specific party?

---

### Long version

In the United States, when people register to vote, they can apparently register with a particular party (or as independent; or maybe they can decline to answer).  In some states, this list is apparently public.  From what I understand, this may or may not impact people's ability to vote in primary elections.  I am **not** asking why this system exists in the USA (that is [addressed here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/34822/130)), so how or why this happens in the USA exactly is not relevant to my question.

This public registry strikes me as very weird.  Although it doesn't directly determine election outcome, many of the reasons why secret ballot is important would also apply to party registration (people could be bullied or paid to register with a particular party, companies could discriminate against people registered with a particular party, etc.).

How unique is publicly registering to vote with a particular party?  Is this exclusively American or do there exist other countries with a similar system?

Comment: I think that in many European (and probably many other countries in the world as well), party affiliation is immediately assumed to be equal to a 'vote' for that party in all elections and on all matters (referendums and such). Also, most people who participate are generally considered to belonging to party. In some countries, there may not be any other option - i.e. you *have* to declare a party affiliation to take part in the process. On the other hand, in the U.S., the plurality of voters are registered as independent. Many may never vote for a major party candidate, but many will.

Comment: As you wrote, the existence of private party membership lists is quite common (after all, how else would you distinguish members from non-members). Now, whether these are public or not is indeed an interesting question!

Comment: Also, something over 10% of those who register with a major party in the U.S, on average, vote for another partisan candidate (or an independent). A larger percentage, again on average, don't vote at all. There are no guarantees in the American system (as has been learned harshly recently).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are people asked for their party affiliation when registering to vote in the United States?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/34822/why-are-people-asked-for-their-party-affiliation-when-registering-to-vote-in-the)

Comment: I think you need to think about updating the question. As it stands, it has an incorrect premise. Party registration rules differ state to state. Additionally, party registration has no impact on voting in the general elections. If your question concerns primary elections, you need to specify that or ask a separate question as primary elections are not a function of the state, but a private event.

Comment: The linked question is unrelated to my question.  I'm asking if the system exists in other countries.  I've edited my question such that it includes less context.  The context was apparently distracting people, leading to an entirely different question being listed as duplicate and an answer which doesn't address the question at all.

Comment: I believe most systems that are based on British Political systems do a reverse order of the U.S. where the elections are more a case of determining how many seats each party gets followed by the parties discussing among them selves which members should fill a particular seat in parliament.

Comment: Also a quick point, that, aside from possibly restricting who you can vote for in a primary vote, your party registration has little importance to the average American unless you actually run for a partisan elected office (some position are non-partisan).  As such, Americans can change political parties with ease (I was going to say without any inconvenience, but voter registration in many if not all states, is part of the process of obtaining/renewing a driver's license.  Most Americans would say that associating the DMV with Sloths is uncalled for.  Sloths aren't that slow in real life.

Comment: @hszmv Huh, voter registration associated with obtaining a driver's license?  How do foreign residents drive?  My wife had a driving license in Iowa but she certainly wasn't allowed to vote there… Now we're drifting farther and farther off-topic.

Comment: @gerrit It's not a mandatory process to register to vote when you get a driver's licenses and if you are a foreign resident looking to obtain citizenship, registering to vote while your not yet a citizen is a good way to ensure you won't be allowed to become a U.S. citizen (the naturalization process will almost certainly find out through background checks.).   There are also some places where non-citizen residents can vote in elections (usually at the local level on the basis of "a non-citizen resident is still part of the community".

Comment: @gerrit Also, potential jurors are usually selected from the pool of registered voters and your immigration status is questioned there as well, since only citizens can serve on juries.  I do have family that were legal residents with driver's licenses prior to receiving naturalized citizenship, so I'll ask them next time I can how that process worked.

Comment: In all states except North Dakota, one has to be registered to vote in order to vote. What @hszmv was referring to is the [motor voter law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Voter_Registration_Act_of_1993). The intent was to make it easier to register to vote. Registering to vote does not necessarily entail registering with a party.

Comment: The big difference may not be so big after all if one considers what voter registration and party affiliation correspond to elsewhere. Example Germany: Every citizen is automatically registered with an address and thereby can vote (this is as if everybody in the US actively went to register and leaving the affiliation field blank). Independently from this, you can actively seek "club membership" in a party and participate there, i.e., discuss and influence their goals, pay member fees, and vote on internal matters such as who to nominate for public elections *(continued)*

Comment: *(cont)* The German SPD has less than half a million members compared to about 12 million votes in the last Federal election, so *obviously* one need not be a party member to vote for them. And vice versa, while it is also obvious that members typically align very strongly with the party politics (why else would they even pay for membership?) and many might grudgingly vote for a candidate of their party just support the party policy even if they don't like that candidate specifically, there is also the case that they *don't* vote for that candidate ("that'll teach 'em!") but uphold membership

Comment: *(cont*) In the end, the difference is not that big after all, except that the two concepts of being identified as a voter and as being allowed to participate in the formation of will of a party are handled *somewhat* jointly but still separately in the US system

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But — party membership in Germany is certainly not public.

Comment: @DavidHammen Thank you.  Yes, there are other ways to register to vote within the U.S.  It's just that most Americans will do so when they are getting their driving license.

Comment: @hszmv Only since 1993, which was when the National National Voter Registration Act was passed, and that was possible only because the 103rd Congress had a strongly Democratic House and Senate and a Democratic President. Only 21 of the 175 Republican representatives and only 5 of the 43 Republican senators voted for the bill.

Comment: @gerrit Party membership is not necessarily public in the US. Aside: In those states that do require declaring a preferred party so as to be able to vote in that party's primary, that does not qualify as party membership. Some states that require that preference make that preference public. Others do not. Some states report all of the elections, including primaries, in which a voter has participated. Others do not. What is releasable to the public varies very much from state to state. The only item that is non-releasable in every state is ones Social Security number, or any part thereof.

Comment: DV because this question is based on the incorrect premise that people in the US register with a party.

Comment: @shoover Huh, they don't?  I thought there were such things as "registered democrats" and "registered republicans".  Is there not?

Comment: @gerrit It's not universal. According to the [University of Virginia Center for Politics](https://centerforpolitics.org/crystalball/articles/registering-by-party-where-the-democrats-and-republicans-are-ahead/), 31 of the 50 states, plus the District of Columbia, require registration by party. The other 19 states do not.

Comment: @shoover If it's true in 31 out of 50 states (+ DC), how is the question based on an incorrect premise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting question and I spent a while digging into it. I believe the short answer to your question is that choosing a party while registering to vote *is pretty unique* to the United States.

While some things [compulsory voter registration](https://aceproject.org/epic-en/CDTable?view=country&question=VR008) and [compulsory voting](https://www.idea.int/data-tools/data/voter-turnout/compulsory-voting) are not unique and there are a [wide variety of voter registration techniques](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2020/10/30/from-voter-registration-to-mail-in-ballots-how-do-countries-around-the-world-run-their-elections/) different countries (and states) use, I found very little to suggest that *party registration* is as common a component of that process in other countries as it is in the united states. In fact, using the "registering with a political party" semantics you use to search for information seemed to exclusively yield information specific to the United States. This may be because I'm searching in English and from a US IP address however I played with the phrasing quite a bit in order to get international results and still had no luck.

Also, as noted by some commenters, voter registration/party lists in the US are not quite as public as you might think. I found [this great breakdown by state](https://www.ncsl.org/research/elections-and-campaigns/access-to-and-use-of-voter-registration-lists.aspx) that shares each US state's usage restrictions and what they keep confidential, as well as links to each's process for obtaining the data. That being said, these look like small hurdles for any individual or group with significant resources and weight behind them so I think your "public" premise basically holds.

Back to your question though, I also realized there's another way to research this: open vs closed primaries. Because...

> In a closed primary, only persons who are registered members of a political party may vote the ballot of that political party.
>
> California: [No party preference](https://www.sos.ca.gov/elections/political-parties/no-party-preference)

So, based on that definition, assumably anywhere there are closed primaries then there's a much larger incentive for people to register for a party (so they can vote on the potentially larger pool of candidates before the election). There seems to be a lot more data on this, and here it seems pretty conclusive that [closed primaries are not unique to the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_election#In_Europe)...

> Closed primaries happen in many European countries, while open primaries have so far only occurred in the socialist and social-democratic parties in Greece and Italy, whereas France's Socialist Party organised the first open primary in France in October 2011.

That being said, the party choice is a. not *public* and b. not part of initial voter registration in those countries as far as I could tell. So, I think my initial "short answer" above still holds unless someone can provide evidence to the contrary (in which case I'm happy to edit this answer). Also note that even in the US, we seem to be heading more towards open primaries and there are a number of groups advocating against and/or discussing the topic...

- https://www.openprimaries.org/mission/
- https://thefulcrum.us/big-picture/Threats-to-democracy/closed-primary
- https://www.deseret.com/utah/2022/7/16/23177307/independent-vs-unaffiliated-whats-the-difference-independent-american-party-utah

Answer (score 2):

Frame challenge, I think you are missunderstanding what registering for a political party actually does. It doesn't restrict your votes in the actual election in any way and these votes are secret. It is more comparable to putting a sign on your lawn advertising for a political party. In both cases you are making a public statement that you support a particular political party. Whether you actually vote for them is independent of that statement and will remain secret.

Comment: But is it compulsory to register with an existing party in order to be able to vote, or is there some other kind of nudging or pressure involved?

Comment: @Lykanion It is my understanding that you need to register with party if you want to vote in their primary but that is a party internal vote where the party choses their candidate. For the actual state elections no registration with any party is required.

Comment: The parties themselves would love for party affiliation to be a proxy for how people vote, but split-ticket voting looks to be back on the rise after declining for the past 20 years. According to [Gallup](https://news.gallup.com/poll/15370/party-affiliation.aspx), there are more registered Independents than there are Republicans or Democrats.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, nor does it tell me anything I didn't already know, nor does it contradict anything implied in the question. And AIUI registering for a political party _is_ required to vote in primary elections for that party, so although the registration does not restrict votes in the general election, it does restrict votes in the primary election.  In the two-party system, primary elections can be very important — and many places in the US are "safe seats" and thus de facto one-party systems, making primaries even more important.

Comment: @gerrit As with so much in the USA, whether you are required to be registered for a particular party to vote in their primary differs state by state. In some states with "open primaries" voters (or in some only independent voters) can choose which to vote in at some or all primary elections. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_primaries_in_the_United_States

Comment: @Lyknion, NO. You do not need to register with any party. I registered 'Independent' (non-affiliated) at the age of 18 and have been so since.

Comment: @gerrit You understand it incorrectly. It's only some states that require party registration in order to vote in a primary. This is done on a state-by-state basis. Other states allow people to vote in whatever primary they want, no party registration required, but do record that a person voted in the primary for party X to ensure that that same person doesn't also vote in the primary for party Y.

Comment: @DavidHammen If people can vote in any primary, what's the point of registering with a party?

Comment: @gerrit That depends on the state but registering with a party can help show that party how much support it has in any given area which can impact how they do things.

Comment: @origimbo Fair enough, but that has 0% relation with my question. which is not about the United States, but about the rest of the world.  I have deleted the tag [tag:united-states] from the question, which was a mistake and is causing confusion.

Comment: Additionally some states use "jungle primaries" where all candidates are voted regardless of the two parties and the two candidates who receive the biggest plurality of votes will run against each other for the same seat.  Because the primary is non-partisan, it's not uncommon for the general election to be a vote between two candidates of the same party.

Comment: @gerrit: Voters are generally allowed to vote in *one* party's primary, not both.  Having your party stamped on your voter registration card helps enforce the ban on voting in multiple parties' primaries.  Of course, like most things in the US, this varies by state.

Comment: If I remember correctly, one cannot register for a political party for the purposes of voting in WA state. State-level candidates do not run as party candidates and run on their own platforms.  National-level candidates have to declare a party affiliation because parties are part of the governing mechanism at the Federal level.  While it is true that the mechanisms vary widely from to state, this answer only adds to the confusion by making some claims which are not true universally.  It should be edited for clarity.

Comment: @gerrit Different states have different rules, and the same can apply to different parties as well. In states where one does not have to register with a party to vote in that party's primary, those who do register with a party do so to be active in party politics, such as being a candidate for a state or national office. My state has primaries that are open to anyone and caucuses in which only party members can participate.

Comment: @gerrit I think the point of registering with a party is mainly for marketing purposes. You'll receive mail/email from the party asking if you want to volunteer for things like canvassing.